# How to check widget is visible when testing

Tags: flutter, testing, widget-test-flutter

In my case, when I using `ExpansionPanelList`, I need to check widget inside panel is visible.

If not visible, `tester.tap(find.text('More Info'))` will throw exception:

```
Warning: A call to tap() with finder "exactly one widget with text "More Info" (ignoring offstage widgets): Text("More Info", dependencies: [MediaQuery, DefaultTextStyle])" derived an Offset (Offset(400.0, 641.8)) that would not hit test on the specified widget. Maybe the widget is actually off-screen, or another widget is obscuring it, or the widget cannot receive pointer events. Indeed, Offset(400.0, 641.8) is outside the bounds of the root of the render tree, Size(800.0, 600.0). The finder corresponds to this RenderBox: RenderParagraph#1b6b1 relayoutBoundary=up27 The hit test result at that offset is: HitTestResult(HitTestEntry#b18dd(RenderView#408c3), HitTestEntry#a2393()) #0 WidgetController._getElementPoint (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:953:25) #1 WidgetController.getCenter (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:836:12) #2 WidgetController.tap (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:271:18) #3 main. (file:///Users/tommy/Repos/surveyapp/survey/test/widget_test.dart:99:18)
```

How do I check this widget is visible in testing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`hitTestable()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/Finder/hitTestable.html), which produces a finder which only matches if the widget described by your finder is truly visible on the screen. For example:

```dart
  expect(find.text('More Info').hitTestable(), findsOneWidget);
```

In your case, you may need to wait until the `ExpansionPanelList` expands or the list scrolls into view. You may need to use `pumpSettle()` or `ensureVisible()` first.

Comment: Perfect answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

[`RednerObject`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html) has a property called `_needsPaint` and its getter [`debugNeedsPaint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject/debugNeedsPaint.html), when this object is visible it should be `true`.

```dart
final targetWidget = find.text('More Info').evaluate().first;
expect(targetWidget.renderObject!.debugNeedsPaint, isTrue);
```

But when [`ExpansionPanelList`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) close again, the paint state is still showing it has been paint.

---

Another work around is that you can ignore the warning and check the side affect.

For example, when tap the hidden widget, it should pop up some view with text `Hello World`:

```dart
await tester.tap(find.text('More Info'), warnIfMissed: false);
expect(find.text('Hello World'), findsOneWidget);
```